# Cannot apply style to dynamically created elements in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following code:

```
let dynel = document.createElement('div');
dynel.className = 'foo';

dynel.style.width = '5px';
dynel.style.height = '5px';
dynel.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';

document.body.appendChild(dynel);
```

This code works as I expect it to, after appending the dynamic element to the document, a 5 x 5 blue box appears. The problem starts when I try to access the element via its className to style it further:

```
var foo = document.getElementsByClassName('foo');

foo[0].style.top = '50px';
foo[0].style.left = '200px';
```

This code should position the box but it does nothing, what am I doing wrong? Preferably I'm looking for a pure JS solution so no JQuery.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Problem

The default value of the property position of a div is *static*. When you try to set left/right [..] on static element it has no effect on that element.

> static : every element has a static position by default, so the
> element will stick to the normal page flow. **So if there is a**
> **left/right/top/bottom/z-index set then there will be no effect on that**
> **element**. relative : an element's original position remains in the flow
> of the document, just like the static value.

#### Solution

- You have to set the position property in your created element to `absolute`, `fixed` or `relative`.

```js
let dynel = document.createElement('div');
dynel.className = 'foo';

dynel.style.position = "absolute"
dynel.style.width = '5px';
dynel.style.height = '5px';
dynel.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';

document.body.appendChild(dynel);

var foo = document.getElementsByClassName('foo');

foo[0].style.top = '50px';
foo[0].style.left = '200px';
```

Comment: Wow, that was so simple, I can't believe I overlooked the position. I'm kinda ashamed now, many thanks, Idk how long I'd be stuck on that :)

Comment: Wonderful Alex....Only 1 think that Alex missed is position:relative; thing

Comment: @ImranRafiqRather relative worked I thought it will not, I have updated it

Comment: CHEERS :) Only this part was missing... And a crucial one as well... Why because fixed stays where ever it is used. absolute also depending on how we use it comes out of the normal flow...But relative is the only case where we can use top,left,right, bottom and yet the element stays in normal page flow :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to ensure that `foo[0]` has the `position: absolute;` style set.

Comment: @krecik2000: Note that with position:absolute: your element will come out of normal flow of execution :) Just wanted to add that :) If this is you implementation that's fine :) If not use position:relative; insteal :) Cheers

Answer (score 1):

`top`, `left`, `right`, `bottom` works on those elements in which `position` property is not `static`. But either `absolute` or `relative` or `fixed`.

As per your requirement use any of the 3 values in your CSS and styles will start to apply. Something like this would work (But it depends how you want you implemention of the code)

```
var foo = document.getElementsByClassName('foo');

foo[0].style.position = "relative";
foo[0].style.top = '50px';
foo[0].style.left = '200px';
```

**NOTE:** `position:fixed` and `position:absolute` would get your element out of the normal code flow and you will have to adjust accordingly.

Comment: just verify that 'relative' works the same as 'static'.  Only 'absolute' and 'fixed' work with top, left, right, bottom.   Not 'relative'

Comment: @hoogw No!!! relative does take top, bottom, left, right properties. 
Do cross check dear. 

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

Here is the Demo for you. Enjoy

https://codepen.io/emmeiWhite/pen/PoJgoQd?editors=0100

First thing is understanding how `position:relative` works.
Spend some time around and practice. You will learn more hopefully.

CHEERS !!! :)

Comment: Hi, Imran Rafiq Rather , I follow your advise, Spend some time around and practice, I did learn more, see below. I create 3 example for each, in below answer. Thanks.  I gave you credit in my answer at the beginning.

Comment: @hoogw Glad that you practised and learned more :)

Answer (score 1):

I was inspired by @Imran Rafiq Rather to give the details example for each situation:

1. relative

If you just want to adjust position a little bit relative to its default position, use key word "relative"

Default position is 'static' position

```
var foo = document.getElementsByClassName('foo');

foo[0].style.position = "relative";  // works almost the same as default or 'static', because 'relative' is relative to it's 'static' position. 

foo[0].style.top = '50px';
foo[0].style.left = '200px';
```

https://codepen.io/hoogw/pen/QWqRdBY

[image]

2. absolute

we usually want to relative to its parent div, should use 'absolute'

```
var foo = document.getElementsByClassName('foo');

foo[0].style.position = 'absolute';  // relative to its parent div

foo[0].style.top = '50px';
foo[0].style.left = '200px';
```

https://codepen.io/hoogw/pen/GRMaWKB?editors=1100
[image]

3. fixed

If you want to relative to whole page, use 'fixed'

```
var foo = document.getElementsByClassName('foo');

foo[0].style.position = 'fixed';  // relative to whole page, whole html body document

foo[0].style.top = '50px';
foo[0].style.left = '200px';
```

https://codepen.io/hoogw/pen/yLzWMvJ
[image]

[image]
Here is link to document https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position